# Trying to understand the iterative method for solving recurrences in this example

Tags: recurrence-relation

This question: [Solving the recurrence T(n) = 3T(n-2) with iterative method](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24290/solving-the-recurrence-tn-3tn-2-with-iterative-method) has a pretty straightforward step-by-step for solving this particular recurrence.  But, I'm having trouble understanding two things.

1) How dos OP arrive at this general form?  If we know `T(n)=3T(n−2)` and `T(n−2)=3T(n−4)`, then my substitution gives:

```
T(n)=3T*3T(n−4)
```

Why is it not 3T*3T, or 3T^2?  Is it some specific behavior of T that determines this?

```
T(n)=3∗3T(n−4)

leading to the general form:

T(n)=3kT(n−2k)
```

2) where does the above k variable come from, exactly?  I understand that you'd combine the 3s to have 3^2, but how do you replace 3^2 with 3^k?

Thanks in advance!